# Is it possible to use form attribute in angularjs for form validation?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation, angularjs-forms

Please think in angularjs way.

Actually my layout is different.

I have input fields inside form and also have input fields outside form, this is a special case in my product.

I know about **form attribute** in HTML5

But

**In AngualrJS:**
I want to achieve outside form input fields works as good as inside form input field works for validation purpose.

> Is it possible? 
>  We can not remove the place of **form** tag.

If Yes please guide me.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl" >
  <h6>Validation Example</h6>

  <form id="frm" name="myForm" novalidate>
    Inside form 
    <p>
      <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
    </p>
  </form>

  Outside form
  <p>Email:<br>
  <input form="frm" type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
  </p>

</div>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/c5VsBRDjDojbMNkfiVPM?p=preview)

Comment: You can set form to parent element as well as create several forms -- does not it solve problem?

Comment: No we can not do this things. Do you have any solution without doing this.
Example is just a scenario.

Comment: Another thing is if your only problem is that you cant move form tag -- you always can add parent form (add ng-form to parent div ).